# Django Model Manager related filter

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to filter the related entries in the manager:

```
class UserTravelsCarsManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(UserTravelsCarsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user=user)

class TravelsCars(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
    objects = UserTravelsCarsManager()

class UserTravelsManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(UserTravelsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user=user)

class Travels(models.Model, ClonableMixin):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(TravelsCars)
    ...

    objects = UserTravelsManager()
```

It won't work by itself. I get all of the cars for all users. I've tried:

```
return super(UserTravelsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user=user, vehicle__user=user)
```

Which also doesn't work.

UPDATE:
Just to be clear the entries for `Travels` are filtered. Just the related `TravelsCars` aren't filtered if I query them through `Travels`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `super(UserTravelsCarsManager, self).get_query_set().filter...` try to use `self.filter(user=user)`. Same in `UserTravelsManager`

Comment: *What* is the same result as before? What happens? What do you see? What error do you get?

Comment: I mean I get the same entries as before..that means unfiltered...entries for all users instead of entries just for the current (logged in) user...